# Get another value in the same row from my $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

So, in my database I got the table `perso` *(= characters)* filled with rows of different characters. There is a column `perso_name` and `perso_fullname`

Here is the form :

```
<form method="post">
<select name="selectperso" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="op1">Option1</option>
    <option value="op2">Option2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="validperso" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

I did a script saying that OP1 and OP2 are the "perso_name" values. But the problem is that i want to insert into my another mysql database the full name of the character the user took.

```
$erreur = 0;
$whitelist = array('op1');    
// Errors variables
$erreurpersowhitelist = NULL;

if (isset($_POST['validperso'])) {
    $personnage = $_POST['selectperso'];     
    if(!in_array($_POST['selectperso'], $whitelist))
    {
        $erreur++;
        $erreurpersowhitelist = "Personnage non disponible (gros malin ;) )";
    }  
    if ($erreur !== 0) {            
        echo "<br><br> ". $erreur . " erreur(s) trouvée(s) lors du choix du personnage :";
        echo "<br><br> ". $erreurpersowhitelist." "; 
    }
    else {    
        $query=$db->prepare('UPDATE users SET personnage = "'. $personnage .'" WHERE username = "'. $username .'"');
        $query->execute();    
        $_SESSION['personnage'] = $personnage;    
        header('Location: index.php');    
    } 
}
```

*(P.S : the echo are in french but it dosn't matter for the question, they are just errors if the user do something bad)*

How can I change my `$personnage` to the `full_name` version of `$_POST['personnage'] ? (Personnage = Character if you wanted to know)`

If there is some security flaws, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, can't get what is wrong here and what you want to do.

Comment: "$_POST['selectperso']" as told in the form select contain the values of the form. For example, OP1 or OP2. There is no post personnage, look into the variables, $personnage is post selectperso. Nothing is wrong with the code, what i want to know is how to put perso_fullname instead of perso_name in my other MYSQL Database, knowing that perso_fullname is another value in the same row as perso_name

Answer (score 0):

You could fill your  values with a database field (an ID, or any other unique field), and then you'll be able to get the data you need from your database.

Example with an ID: TABLE perso (id, perso_name, perso_fullname)

In your html form, fill your options with the ids

```
<select name="selectperso" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Then in your validation form, retrieve the character name from your database:

```
$query=$db->query('SELECT full_name FROM perso WHERE id='.$db->escape($_POST['selectperso'])); //get the full_name from the perso's id
```

If you don't want to use an id, you can use your perso_name instead as long as it's unique.

Comment: So, this seems good. I already got ID, perso_name and perso_fullname in my table "perso" so i guess this is good. Only problem is that i got 2 questions. What is the equivalent to "escape" in PDO, and once i SELECTED perso_fullname, how can i put this new acquired value in the second database ? ( UPDATE users SET personnage = ???? )

Comment: @Elyox, you can get it before your update query as mentioned in above query.

Comment: @Eleyox, Sry, I didn't know which DB library you were using. if you're using PDO, simply replace $db->escape with $db->quote or use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections. See Shaunak Shukla's comment for your 2nd question, basically you just have to fetch the result from the query